# Why does Visual Studio fail to compile C# long TryParse correctly in predicate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tryparse

This code compiles:

```
public static void SetBackLink(dynamic viewBag, NameValueCollection queryString, bool defaultToServicePage = false) {
    if (defaultToServicePage && string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewBag.BackLinkUrl)) {
        if (!long.TryParse(queryString["serviceId"], out long serviceId)) {
            return;
        }
        viewBag.BackLinkUrl = UserEntityService.CalculationService.GetServicePageUrl(serviceId);
        viewBag.BackLinkText = UserEntityService.CalculationService.GetServiceTitle(serviceId);
    }
}
```

This code has compiler error *Use of unassigned local variable 'serviceId'* on the third line:

```
public static void SetBackLink(dynamic viewBag, NameValueCollection queryString, bool defaultToServicePage = false) {
    if (defaultToServicePage && string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewBag.BackLinkUrl) && long.TryParse(queryString["serviceId"], out long serviceId)) {
        viewBag.BackLinkUrl = UserEntityService.CalculationService.GetServicePageUrl(serviceId);
        viewBag.BackLinkText = UserEntityService.CalculationService.GetServiceTitle(serviceId);
    }
}
```

I have the following version of Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.4.5
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.5+29806.167
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752
Installed Version: Enterprise
```

Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Maybe caused by the `dynamic`. If change to specific type, it has compiled. I also cannot understand why this not compile.

Comment: Thanks. I reported it as a compiler bug.

Comment: This is not a compiler bug: it's a very definite consequence of how `dynamic` works. Eric Lippert ended up doing a nice write-up: [Part 1](https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/14/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle/), [Part 2](https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/19/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle-part-2/)

Comment: FWIW, using `dynamic` usually creates 2 more problems for every problem it solves

Comment: @canton7 I updated the bug report. Thanks :)